# Crystal reports- divide a record in the detail section to display by the total divisable

Tags: sql-server, crystal-reports

I need to get crystal reports to display the below:

Display n records
Where record divided by x = n

My example- I have stock that comes into my business which we book on as a total quantity say 300. We can get 10 on a pallet so this quantity equals 30 pallets. I want crystal to display each pallet as a separate record rather than the total 300. Is this possible or would we need to change the booking in procedure to reflect that one pallet equals one record?

I am using crystal reports 2008.

Thanks,
Kyle

Comment: You could do this with groupings but how would all the other columns on the record be divided?  It is easier to have your data stored at a lower granularity and roll up than it is to drill down on totals.

Comment: How do you get the data number of pallets?

Comment: Show us your current result of report and desired one so we can help you

Comment: I have Product A which is booked in as 264, product b booked in as 132 and product c booked in as 66. All Pallets are divisible by 66- we have another field which gives us pallet quantities. Currently this will only display as 3 records, one for each product but i want this to display 4 records for product A, 2 records for product B and 1 for product C. Thanks

Comment: Create a dataset. Fill the dataset using the code and use the dataset in your report.  This may not be very efficient but gets the job done

Comment: It would much better if you show some the sample data and how the output should look like